# How can I set MHT-body for mail sending through Exchange Server?

Tags: c#, exchange-server, exchangewebservices, exchange-server-2007, ews-managed-api

I have a message as an [MHT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MHTML)-File. Now I am searching for a way to set this for a mail to send through Exchange Server (with Exchange Web Service). When I set it as a MIME-Content, the parts (picture and text) will be attached as attachments (JPEG file and HTML file). But I need a way to set the whole MHT as a body with all containing objects.

The following is attaching the MHT as attachments. What is wrong?

```
EmailMessage message = new EmailMessage(service);
message.MimeContent = new MimeContent { Content = File.ReadAllBytes(bodyPath) };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have it solved now with the Component for Exchange WebService programming from Indepenendent-Soft.